# The plurality in the phrase "jaunes et vert foncé"

Tags: adjectifs, accord, pluriel, coordination

> Il n'y a que des habits **jaunes et vert foncé**.

---

I’m not sure why the plurality applies only to the colour "jaunes", and not to the "vert". Shouldn’t the sentence be constructed more like:

> Il n'y a que des habits **jaunes et verts foncé**.

or

> Il n'y a que des habits **jaunes et verts foncés**.

---

An additional question: Does the adjective "foncé" refer only to the word "vert", or does its meaning extend to the "jaunes"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A rule says that compound color adjectives are invariable.

> *Des chandails **bleu marine***.
>
> *J'ai vu des robes **jaune citron***.
>
> *Les feuilles de cet arbre sont **rouge pâle***.

Here are an exercise and some theory about color adjectives (in French only): http://www.ccdmd.qc.ca/media/ffiches_a_14Couleurs.pdf.
Also, a [French Wiktionary](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Th%C3%A9saurus:couleur/fran%C3%A7ais#Pluriel_des_noms_de_couleur) page about it.

---

As for your second question, I think *foncé* applies to *vert* only, because

1. *Jaune* is plural, so it is a simple color adjective.
2. Otherwise I think the sentence would be *Il n'y a que des habits jaune foncé et vert foncé* or something.

Comment: So am I right in thinking that we should turn "une robe **verte**" into "une robe **vert foncé**"? And on the same note, is "une robe **rouge vermeil**" the correct phrase to use instead of "une robe **rouge vermeille**"? Merci.

Comment: You're right on both phrases. In addition to Archa's answer : when an item has several colors, they also become invariable. So if you have some items that are yellow and some that are green, you'd write "des vêtements jaunes et verts", but if your clothes are both colors (e.g. striped) you'd write "des vêtements jaune et vert".

Comment: Merci. So does the original sentence *"Il n'y a que des habits **jaunes et vert foncé**"* mean that there are **some yellow** clothes and **some dark green** ones, instead of there being only some clothes with the mixed colours?

Comment: That's quite plausible.

Answer (score -1):

In french, color adjectives are variables.

You can say

> "Des pulls verts."

But ! If the color is also a noun, for example 'orange', it will be invariable.

> "Des pulls orange."

But ! If the color is in two parts, it will be variable only if there is no dash between them, and only one the first word.

> "Des pulls bleu-vert **(no s).**"
>
> "Des pulls bleu**S** ciel **(no s)**."

So in your example, you should say :

> "Il n'y a que des habits jaune**s** et vert**s** foncé."

So in the first sentence, "foncé" can refer to "jaunes" or "verts" (but "vert foncé" is way more usual than "jaune foncé" so it is probably refering to "verts").

---

Sources : http://www.projet-voltaire.fr/blog/regle-orthographe/des-maillots-%C2%AB-orange-%C2%BB-ou-%C2%AB-oranges-%C2%BB

http://www.projet-voltaire.fr/blog/regle-orthographe/les-bleu-ciel-les-bleus-ciel-ou-les-bleus-ciels

Comment: *Des pulls bleus ciel* is incorrect, *bleu* should have no *s* too.